# Is there a way to reference to the root of all jobs (Dashboard) via a variable in Jenkins to use in a path

Tags: jenkins

I am using a "Trigger call/build on other project" build step on my job A where I call job B.

Because of the job/folder structure I need to call this job B by traversing up (e.g. *../../Global jobs/Job B/*) Also see image.

[image]

I am wondering is there also a way to call this job with a more absolute path preferably  with an environment variable (if it exists)

For example
${JENKINS_JOB_ROOT}/Global jobs/Job B/

Current job structure as seen from Dashboard is:

**Job A**
*Dashboard/Client X/Project A/Job A*

**Job B**
*Dashboard/Global jobs/Job B*